# select another path object on hover in Raphael

Tags: javascript, hover, raphael

I'm new to both javascript and Raphael. I've created two rings with multiple paths in each ring. I want to change state of path in outer ring when someone hovers over a path at same location in the inner ring. For some reason I'm not able to do this and stuck for a long while. Can someone please help?
In the example below, 'b' is prefix to path ids in inner ring and 'c' for outer rings. I'm trying to identify the id first and then perform actions. I don't know if this is a good way of doing things, so any suggestions on that will be helpful too.

```
e.mouseover(function(){
    e.attr(style[style.length-1]);
    if (e.node.id[0]=='b'){
      var i = e.node.id;
      i = i.replace("b","c");
      document.getElementById(i).attr({fill: 'red'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById(i).setAttribute('fill', 'red')
```